# How can Mjolnir Hammer joins the Far Eastern Magic Nap Society of Summer?

Tags: culture, love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

By the time the club was established, Mjolnir Hammer, Dekomori Sanae, was a junior high student. How can she join the club? Was it because her junior high and the senior high that Tyrant Eye, Takanashi Rikka, attends is an escalator school? Is it common for student of an escalator school to attend club of the higher school in Japan?

If we don't count Dekomori as an official member of the club, then the club would have only 4 members (Dark Flame Master, Tyrant Eye, Mori Summer, Tsuyuri Kumin) which is one less than the minimum for a club.

Note: I'm not sure that the school is an escalator school. The uniform is similar and I think Yuuta once said to Dekomori, "Oh, you attend our junior high, huh?" which suggest that the school is an escalator school, but I'm not sure if I remember it correctly.

Comment: It always seemed more informal than that; nobody would question her presence in the school because of its status as an escalator school, yet she wasn't officially part of the club

Comment: But the teacher who they asked to be their club advisor didn't object to Dekomori joining at all. She did object when Rikka wanted to enter Chimaera as a member since Chimaera is a cat. Why wouldn't she object to Dekomori as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E4%BA%8C%E7%97%85%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E6%81%8B%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84!),
The school is escalator school in anime version only.
Dekomori is anime only character that problem is not exist LN version..

Club system in escalator school is depends on the school.

Some schools have totally separate clubs.
Some schools have shared one club between junior high and high.
Some other school have joint club for cultural club and separate club for sports related club.

I'll try to add some reference about clubs in escalator school. (sorry links are in Japanese.)

- From answer of [this question](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1475834509)(Does escalator school have shared club?), most school share the club between junior high and high. (The answer said they also have shared "seitokai" Student council)
- Son of [this blog](http://e-shoshin.com/?p=2578) author "graduated" baseball club in junior high, and joined high school club next day. so in this case clubs are separated.
- [This article](http://logosdivinityguildworks.org/sub07/) said one of good thing of escalator school is share the club.

Comment: I think you're on to something here. More reference on escalator scholl clubs please?

Comment: Tried to find but I can found article in Japanese only. sorry.